# Should "trim" and "trim-tab" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently edited [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50781/878) to add the [trim](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trim) tag. I noticed there is another tag named [trim-tab](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trim-tab) with almost identical description. Is there a reason to keep them both around?

Answer (score 6):

### I think [trim] needs a new description

Not all aircraft use tabs for trim -- some use other devices instead, and the [trim] tag should cover all means of trim, not just trim tabs.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there are only 6 questions tagged with [trim-tab](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trim-tab) but 37 questions tagged with [trim](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trim).

Given the low number of questions specifically about the trim tab, I think we should **merge all questions to [trim](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trim)**.